# Unity networking, make player disappear for all clients

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I need to make the player disappear when he gets in car. Right now, it works as a single-player, but since I am new to "Unet" I don't really know how to achieve this, I tried some ways, but they didn't work. Here is script:

```
    [Client]
  void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
 {
 //so if we hit car
 if(hit.collider.tag == "Vehicle")
 {
     //if we pressed "E"
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
     {
         //call method to disable some stuff taht should be disabled, like: controller, shoot, weapons etc.
         if (isServer)
             CmdCall(inVehicle, hit);
         else
             RpcCall(inVehicle, hit);
     }
 }
 }
[Command]
 void CmdCall(bool invehicle, ControllerColliderHit hit){

 RpcCall(inVehicle, hit);
 }
 [ClientRpc]
 void RpcCall(bool invehicle, ControllerColliderHit hit)
 {

 disable(inVehicle, hit);
 }
```

> I can't see any errors in console but I cant enter play mode cause there are some compiler errors, which again i cant see in console. thank you for any tip, comment, downvote, upvote, or hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `NetworkServer.UnSpawn ()` and `NetworkServer.Spawn ()`